# Spark RDD Inner Join Performance after collecting a sample of data

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have two Spark Jobs where they read two datasets from a Hadoop cluster, load the data to RDDs and perform an inner join. The difference between those two jobs is a sampling operation before the inner join, which I need it for building a histogram of the data sets. The sampling operation is performed for both data sets as `rdd.sample(false, 0.01 261).collect()` (I'm not using the `takeSample()` method). The job that integrates the sampling procedure runs much faster in terms of execution time than the other job that simply performs the inner join (the time difference is about ~-25%!).

```java
JavaRDD<String> rddTxtFilesA = jsc.textFile("hdfs://node1:9000/user/datasetA.csv");
JavaRDD<String> rddTxtFilesB = jsc.textFile("hdfs://node1:9000/user/datasetB.csv");

JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, Double, Double>> rddTuplesA = rddTxtFilesA.map((String line) -> {
      String[] elements = line.split("\t");
      return new Tuple3<>(elements[0], Double.parseDouble(elements[1]), Double.parseDouble(elements[2]));
});

JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, Double, Double>> rddTuplesB = rddTxtFilesB.map((String line) -> {
      String[] elements = line.split("\t");
      return new Tuple3<>(elements[0], Double.parseDouble(elements[1]), Double.parseDouble(elements[2]));
});

//The different code part in the two Spark Jobs where sampling operation occurs
rddTuplesA.sample(false, 0.01, 261).collect().forEach((tuple) ->
          //build histogram
);

rddTuplesB.sample(false, 0.01, 261).collect().forEach((tuple) ->
          //build histogram
);
//sampling operation finishes

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple3<String, Double, Double>> pairRDDA = rddTuplesA.flatMapToPair(...);
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple3<String, Double, Double>> pairRDDB = rddTuplesB.flatMapToPair(...);

CustomPartitioner cp = ...

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Tuple3<String, Double, Double>, Tuple3<String, Double, Double>>> joinedRDD = pairRDDA.join(pairRDDB,cp);

long count = joinedRDD.count();
```

It seems that the `collect()` operation somehow affects the job and makes it running faster. Any thoughts why is this happening? I'm using the 3.1.3 version of Spark.

Note also that I have replaced the `collect()` method with the `count()` method and the same happens. Thus, I suspect that it is the **action** that somehow affects the job's execution time.

Comment: Interesting question! Can you add the code for both of your joins please? That will help us in answering you :)